# Java - BufferedImage causing high memory usage exacerbated by multiple threads?

Tags: java, memory, bufferedimage

There are many similar threads for this problem here but I haven't found a solution. Basically, what I'm doing is asynchronously updating an ArrayList. This isn't really relevant, though, because the high memory usage occurs whether or not I run synchronously or asynchronously, but it is less significant (still significant imo) when I run synchronously than when I run asynchronously (presumably because the BufferedImage is stored on multiple threads rather than being overwritten on the single thread multiple times).

Here's what I do for the asynchronous part. Bear with me, first time I've ever done an asynchronous task so it's probably shitty, but it runs.

```
public void updateAllShows() {
    // I find it runs faster even when thread amount > # of threads from CPU
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(array size)

    // All the Future tasks we execute later
    ArrayList<Future<MyShowComp>> tasks = new ArrayList

    // This holds the new MyShowComp that all the Futures calculate
    ArrayList<MyShowComp> tempArray = new ArrayList

    for (MyShowComp comp : array) {
        final MyShowComp c = comp;
        FutureTask<?> t = new FutureTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // I'll detail this method in a moment
                tempArray.add(updateShowAsync(c,false));
            }
        }, null);
        // Now that future task is created, we add it to the list of tasks
        tasks.add(t);
    }

    // Cycle through and execute every stored task
    for (FutureTasks)
        executor.execute(task);

    executor.shutdown();
    if (shutdown finished)
        array = tempArray;
        // Do some sorting and add to panel
}
```

That's that, pretty simple. Now the trouble part, where I update the show's image:

```
public MyShowComp updateShowAsync(MyShowComp c, boolean bool) {
    //
    // Bunch of irrelevant code, already tested, doesn't affect memory usage
    //

    BufferedImage img = null;

    // We pull the image from particular URL
    img = ImageIO.read(url);

    // Resize the image accordingly (this method makes little to no difference in memory)
    img = resize(img);

    return new MyShowComp(img);
}
```

Why is it that the BufferedImage img is always held in memory even when it's completely dereferenced? If I return a MyShowComp with an entirely separate & null BufferedImage, the problem still persists. The original BufferedImage img remains in memory and simply doesn't go away. It only fixes when I comment out `img = ImageIO.read` and skip it entirely. I've tried img.flush(), img = null, etc., nothing works. Is there a way to force a complete dereference so GC will do its job?

-----   EDIT ------

Here is some quick test code so that whoever wants to can test for themselves.

**FrameTest.java**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class FrameTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private ArrayList<MyShowComp> array;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FrameTest window = new FrameTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public FrameTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        String quick = "Quick";
        array = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<21;i++)
            array.add(new MyShowComp(quick, quick, quick, null));

        JButton btnUpdateShows = new JButton("Update Shows");
        btnUpdateShows.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                updateAllShows();               
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpdateShows, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame.getContentPane(), "Click the update button and watch the program's memory usage everytime you do. It'll progressively get higher.");
    }

    private void updateAllShows() {
        // Async method version 1
        /*ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(array.size());
        ArrayList<FutureTask<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<MyShowComp> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        for (MyShowComp myShowComp : array) {
            final MyShowComp c = myShowComp;
            FutureTask<?> newTask= new FutureTask<Object>(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    temp.add(updateShow(c, false)); 
                }
            }, null);
            tasks.add(newTask);
        }
        for (FutureTask<?> futureTask : tasks) 
            executor.execute(futureTask);

        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            boolean finished = executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            if (finished) {
                array = temp;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Asynch thread interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        // Async method version 2
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(array.size());
        class NewTask implements Callable<MyShowComp> {
            MyShowComp c;
            public NewTask(MyShowComp c) {
                this.c = c;
            }

            public MyShowComp call() {
                return updateShow(c, false);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Future<MyShowComp>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MyShowComp MyShowComp : array) 
            taskList.add(executor.submit(new NewTask(MyShowComp)));

        ArrayList<MyShowComp> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Future<MyShowComp> future : taskList) {
            try {
                temp.add(future.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        array = temp;
        temp = new ArrayList<>();

        // Synchronous method
        /*ArrayList<MyShowComp> tempTwo = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MyShowComp myShowComp: array) 
            tempTwo.add(updateShow(myShowComp, false));         

        array = tempTwo;*/

    }

    private MyShowComp updateShow(MyShowComp c, boolean b) {

        BufferedImage img = null;
        // Load the images
        try {
            // Random Game of Thrones image from IMDB
            URL url = new URL("http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjM5OTQ1MTY5Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjM3NzMxODE@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,674,1000_AL_.jpg");
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //MyShowComp newComp = new MyShowComp("lol", "Leaks?", "Probably", new ImageIcon(img));
        MyShowComp newComp = new MyShowComp("lol", "Leaks?", "Probably", new ImageIcon(img));
        //System.out.println(newComp);
        img.flush();
        img = null;
        System.gc();
        return newComp;
    }
}
```

**MyShowComp.java**

```
import javax.swing.Icon;

public class MyShowComp {
    private String test, testTwo, testThree;
    private Icon icon;
    public MyShowComp(String test, String testTwo, String testThree, Icon icon) {
        this.test = test;
        this.testTwo = testTwo;
        this.testThree = testThree;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return test + "\n" + testTwo + "\n" + testThree + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: In general: the GC does its job ... when it thinks it is required to do so. Although that isn't guaranteed to really make the GC go ... did you try calling System.gc() just to see if it makes a difference? And btw: how do you measure memory consumption? And finally, consider creating a minimal, viable example, as described in the help center. Your posting contains an awful lot of information, of which **you** actually say "probably not relevant". You want us to help you, so you better spent some time providing the **relevant** pieces in here ...

Comment: I've done extensive testing and I can tell you for sure the pieces I say that aren't relevant, aren't relevant. I discovered the issue lied with a bufferedimage in the class that contains the above code with VisualVM, and I just watch mem usage through task manager each time I run my code. I'll create that viable example in a sec.

Comment: What I mean is: you **say** that this or that isn't relevant; and then half of the code that you give is around that part that you claim isn't relevant. So, you consider the async part to not be relevant, but you still expect us to digest all of that? Again: you want us to help you. So **you** make that as easy as possible. Posting not-relevant code isn't exactly in the "helpful" category.

Comment: Well, I wanted help with the problem at hand, which I attempted by telling everyone that everything else is irrelevant, and not waste anyone's time criticising the rest of my shitty code that isn't causing me any problems currently. I did as you said and uploaded a test program which exhibits the same problem, devoid of any other extraneous code, so you can see for yourself.

Comment: Maybe you step back for a second to understand that you are **new** in this community. There is absolutely no need to become defensive when people tell you how this community works. I understand that you **want** help. But you better **understand** the correct way to use this site to get help. And you know, there is a help center that tells you "what works"; and what doesn't work. For example: you provide example code here, as text. You **never ever** link to external sites and ask us to download stuff from there.

Comment: Sorry about that, truly did not mean to come off as defensive. I'll remove link and paste code as text.

Comment: Ok, much better! One thing though: did you try those System.gc() experiments at some point? As I said initially: the thing with the garbage collector is that it doesn't start when **garbage** exists that **could** be collected. It might only start collecting ... when memory goes short. In other words: you are merely concerned about the memory usage of your system, or did you already face real "issues" there?

Comment: It's definitely the former, I haven't run into any OOM's or anything. I did test with your suggestion of adding in System.gc() and it seems to have helped the synchronous method quite a bit, but the asynchronous' mem usage still gets quite high. The thing is, in each case, the mem usage will top out after a certain amount of runs and stop increasing. I assume this means this isn't a "true" mem leak. When I run my main program which loads more/different images each time, it can top out at nearly a 1gb of mem usage after several consecutive clicks if I'm running the async method so while (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) I haven't run into any errors, I still feel like I should be concerned I'm doing something wrong. I've updated main post with a different process of asynchronization I've tried in FrameTest.java, I'd be grateful if you could take a look and lemme know if I'm doing a no-no when it comes to this thing. All I'm trying to do is asynchronously update each item in the array, which involves fetching the updated image from a website.